# Extract stripes from low contrast grayscale images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to extract stripes from this sample file [sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjEag.png), and the result should look like this one [similar result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Sp1.png). Then, I need to count the number of stripes on the right, and calculate the distance from the end of each left stripe to the end of each adjacent right stripe.

I tried with the following code, but my result [my result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG797.png)is still a little bit away from my target. Here is what I do:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

gray = cv2.imread('input_file.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
sobelY = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
sobelY2 = cv2.Sobel(sobelY, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
sobelY2[sobelY2<0]=0
mask = np.where(sobelY2==0,0,1)

sobelY2 = cv2.normalize(sobelY2, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=65535, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint16)
clahe=cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=6, tileGridSize=(8,8))
sobelY2_clahe = clahe.apply(sobelY2)
sobelY2_clahe = clahe.apply(sobelY2_clahe)
result = np.where(mask!=0,sobelY2_clahe,0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
ax = plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

The input file is in 16 bits format, so I keep it unchanged for accuracy. I do second order Sobel operation in Y direction to high light those stripes, and then I do two times Clahe operations to balance the contrast. To keep the background pixels as 0, I use a mask to set the values back after the Clahe operations.

Any advice is appreciated!

For completeness, I am attaching another more challenged input file for reference[more challenged input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2zq.png).

Edit:
The sobelY2 image pretty much reflects the stripes, but could we make it look better?
[image: The sobelY2 image after manually adjusting the contrast]

I just opened a new question about how to trim each of these stripes based on gray scale values.[trim image based on grayscale values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236119/trim-grayscale-image-based-on-values?noredirect=1#comment124158709_70236119)

Comment: From my observations, you can't locate the left stripes reliably in the sample image. The signal is too weak.

Comment: that's an xray of a lithium battery, right? and you want to count the number of wraps/sheets?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is weak, especially at the bottom left part, but good enough for the bottom right stripes.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Yes sir. Stripes are anode and cathode poles in the battery.

Comment: IMO, you can detect the first stripes and extrapolate by fitting a nonlinear model to predict the next stripes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I exported a sobelY2 image out and adjusted the light and contrast manually in ImageJ, and I can see pretty much most of the stripes except the last a few from the left part(I could not upload the image here, but I will try it by editing my original post). Now my question is, how should I clean up the image to make it look better?

Comment: @XinlongWang: keep doing it by hand. That always works better.