# trim grayscale image based on values

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is the follow up question to my previews one [Extract stripes from low contrast grayscale images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187091/extract-stripes-from-low-contrast-grayscale-images).

After some research and considerations, my question now is how to trim each of the stripes I got from my previous operations.

My stripes are now look like these:
[image: stripe 1]
[image: stripe 2]
and I want to trim them to get only the high lighted parts like:[image: result stripe 1] and [image: result stripe 2]. (some pixels may not be visible due to the low gray scale value)

I tried the otsu threshold in OpenCV, but it does not seem to work because of the majority pixels are background black. In addition, each stripe has different contrast because of the uneven lighting condition.

This job seems to me now is to mark all the pixels on the plateau and drop those below some level, but I have't figure out a good way to do it so far.

Please advice and thanks in advance!

Comment: Try taking the vertical projection, i.e. sum the columns of the image and plot those numbers across the width of the image `np.sum(image, axis=0)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reply. Yes, I tried this way, and I used the first order differences to get the turning points(cutting points), but this method seems not work well for Y direction, so I wonder if there is a more universal method.

Comment: A few more words about my understanding. Pixies that I want to trim off are obviously darker than those I want to keep on the plateau, and the problem is how could I find the boundary pixels.

Comment: what's the goal of this? if you ask for trimming, a literal answer will tell you how to trim. I suspect you don't need to trim, you need something else, and you think you need "trimming".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to make the stripe smaller by trimming off those dark pixels.

Comment: Maybe you can try a clustering algorithm for example k-means clustering, or EM (expectation–maximization) algorithm. It is a classification problem, since you would like to classify the pixels to background or foreground.

Comment: @Kaiwen This seems a nice idea to segment the plateau pixels from background pixels. will update with my result later.